# 500 (Internal Server Error) on heroku using cleardb and php with an ajax request

Tags: php, css, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I created a small application that goes to the amazon api and grabs the asin, and a few other things. This works perfectly fine on my localhost however, once putting it in heroku, it seems to stop working.

I get this error:

```
 GET https://efreiner1-qn.herokuapp.com/printDatabase.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and this stack trace

```
send @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9536
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
display @ main.js:11
(anonymous) @ main.js:7
mightThrow @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3570
process @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3638
```

it seems to be having an error reading the php file, I already needed moved it from /php/file.php to the main folder, but it is still not working.

However, the response I get is a css response that I stuck on top of the php file so I know its hitting it.
Here are 2 screen shots that I took to maybe shed some light.

[image: I am not exactly sure what this is, I hope it helps]

[image: This is the css that it took from the top]

And this is the PHP file, which works on the localhost

```
<style type="text/css">

#table
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
 th
{
    padding: 8px 2px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5264AE;
    border-right: 30px solid #5264AE;
    border-left: 30px solid #5264AE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
 td
{
    padding: 12px 2px 0px 2px;
    border-right: 30px solid #5264AE;
    border-left: 30px solid #5264AE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>


<?php
            include_once('configDB.php');

                 $result = mysql_query("SELECT asin, title, mpn, price FROM amazon");



          echo    "<table id='table'>";
          echo      "<tr>";
          echo        "<th>ASIN</th>";
          echo        "<th>Title</th>";
          echo        "<th>MPN</th>";
          echo        "<th>Price</th>";
          echo      "</tr>";



          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo      "<tr>";
            echo       "<td>".$row{'asin'}."</td>";
            echo       "<td>".$row{'title'}."</td>";
            echo       "<td>".$row{'mpn'}."</td>";
            echo       "<td>".  $row{'price'}."</td>";
            echo     "</tr>";

          }

          echo     "</table>";


?>
```

From what it seems to me, this is a problem from ajax maybe, I am not sure, here is the ajax request

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'printDatabase.php',
        complete: function(response) {
            $('#left').html(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function(result) {

            $('#left').html(result);
        }
    });
```

Thank you, I hope this is enough information

Comment: Why not you turn on the logger in heroku and see what's happening ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to do that, I am a bit new to this.

Comment: You shall use https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries to see the log, however , it runs in your local server well  ?

Comment: it runs perfectly

Comment: I installed that link you sent, but I am afraid I dont know how to use it and no errors are showing in the front screen.

Comment: Errors won't be shown in the front screen, you can see the errors only in the logentries dashbaord

Comment: ok i saw them it shows this » 15 Mar 2017 05:29:47.561 248 <190>1 2017-03-15T09:29:47.196384+00:00 app web.1 - - [15-Mar-2017 09:29:47 UTC] PHP Warning: include_once(configDB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/printDatabase.php on line 33 Heroku/efreiner1-qn

Comment: Have you installed the laravel completely in the heroku or it has enough permission for mentioned file ?

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel, what does it do?

Comment: Sorry which framework you are using ?

Comment: just php with heroku

Comment: if I include the content of the config file to the file i am making a query on i end up getting this error "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()"

Comment: Have you enabled mysql extension in the addons ?

Comment: I have clearDB installed as an extension and I am using that as my database

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
The issue was that I was using `mysql()` instead of `mysqli()` the version of php on my localhost was older of that on the server and therefor worked on my machine but not on the server